# Matrix determinant in template using gaussian elimination

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm having issues to implement the determinant of a matrix inside my matrix template. I'm trying to obtain the determinant by calculating the product of the principal diagonal in the reduced associated matrix. The problem is that it only works for some cases and is not reliable. This is the code for the determinant

```
template <typename T>
T Matrix<T>::Det() const  {
    if (Rows != Cols) {
        cout << "Matrix must be square" << endl;
    }
    Matrix<T> r = Reduced();
    T Det = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<Rows; i++) {
        Det *= r.getValue(i, i);
    }
    return Det;
}
```

Since the Gaussian elimination works, the reduced matrix that I obtain for any given matrix (which fits the criteria to be reduced) is fine, so i thought there wouldn't be any issue, but I haven't been able to see what I'm missing.
Any advice will be welcomed!

**Edit:**
As someone pointed out, here is a minimal reproducible example.
This would be the template

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    unsigned int Rows;
    unsigned int Cols;
    T *Mat;
public:
    Matrix(unsigned int Dim);
    Matrix(unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Cols);
    Matrix(unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Cols, const std::vector<T>& Vec);
    Matrix(unsigned int Dim, const std::vector<T>& Vec);
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& M);
    ~Matrix();
    T& getValue(unsigned int Row, unsigned int Col) const;
    T Det() const;
    Matrix<T> Reduced() const;
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Cols) 
: Rows(Rows), Cols(Cols) {
    if (Rows<=0 || Cols<=0) {
        cout << "Número inválido de filas o columnas" << endl;
    }
    Mat = new T[Rows*Cols];
    for (int i=0; i<Rows*Cols; i++) {
        Mat[i] = 0;
    }
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned int Dim) 
: Rows(Dim), Cols(Dim) {
    if(Rows<=0 || Cols<=0) {
        cout << "Número inválido de filas o columnas" << endl;
    }
    Mat = new T[Rows*Cols];
    for (int i=0; i<Rows*Cols; i++) {
        Mat[i] = 0;
    }
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Cols, const std::vector<T>& Vec) 
: Rows(Rows), Cols(Cols) {
    if (Rows<=0 || Cols<=0) {
        cout << "Número inválido de filas o columnas" << endl;
    }
    Mat = new T[Rows*Cols];
    if (Vec.size() != Rows*Cols) {
        cout << "Los tamaños de la matriz y el vector no son iguales" << endl;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<Rows*Cols; i++) {
        Mat[i] = Vec[i];
    }
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned int Dim, const std::vector<T>& Vec) 
: Rows(Dim), Cols(Dim) {
    if (Rows<=0 || Cols<=0) {
        cout << "Número inválido de filas o columnas" << endl;
    }
    Mat = new T[Rows*Cols];
    if (Vec.size() != Rows*Cols) {
        cout << "Número inválido de filas o columnas" << endl;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<Rows*Cols; i++) {
        Mat[i] = Vec[i];
    }
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& M)
: Rows(M.Rows), Cols(M.Cols), Mat(new T[Rows * Cols]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Rows * Cols; i++)
        Mat[i] = M.Mat[i];
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {
    delete[] Mat;
}

template <typename T>
T &Matrix<T>::getValue(unsigned int Row, unsigned int Col) const  {
    if (Row<0 || Row>=Rows || Col<0 || Col>=Cols) {
        cout << "Índice incorrecto" << endl;
    }
    return Mat[Row*Cols + Col];
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::Reduced() const {
    if (Rows != Cols) {
        cout << "La matriz debe ser cuadrada para reducirse" << endl;
    }
    Matrix<T> Tri(*this);
    
    int n = Rows;
    int m = 0;
    for (int k=0; k<n-1; k++) {
        if (Tri.Mat[k*Cols + k] == 0)
            cout << "La matriz es singular" << endl;
        
        for (int i = k+1; i<n; i++) {
            m = Tri.Mat[i*Cols + k]/Tri.Mat[k*Cols + k];
            for (int j = k+1; j<n; j++) {
                Tri.Mat[i*Cols + j] = Tri.Mat[i*Cols + j] - m*Tri.Mat[k*Cols + j];
            }
            Tri.Mat[i*Cols + k] = 0;
        }
    }
    return Tri;
}

template <typename T>
T Matrix<T>::Det() const  {
    if (Rows != Cols) {
        cout << "Matrix must be square" << endl;
    }
    Matrix<T> r = Reduced();
    T Det = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<Rows; i++) {
        Det *= r.getValue(i, i);
    }
    return Det;
}

template <class T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const Matrix<T> &Shw) {
    for (int i=0; i<Shw.getRows(); i++) {
        os << "| ";
        for (int j=0; j<Shw.getCols(); j++) {
            os << Shw.getValue(i,j) << " ";
        }
        os << "|\n";
    }
    return os;
}
#endif
```

This is the implementation on main.cc

```
#include "matrix.h"
int main() {
    Matrix<double> M1(2, 2, {1, 3, 5, 7});
    cout << M1.Det() << endl;
    
    Matrix<double> M2(3, 3, {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 2, 14});
    cout << M2.Det() << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is the following

```
-8    //This one is okay
-143  //This one is not
```

Comment: For instance, if a calculate the determinant of the square 2x2 matrix {1,3,5,7} it does output -8. But for the 3x3 matrix {1,3,5,7,8,9,11,2,14} prints -143 which is clearly wrong since the correct output would be -273. I do not get any error message.

Comment: In the Reduced() function, the type of variable m must be T.  /*int*/ T m = 0;

Comment: Determinant for `[[1 3 5][7 8 9][11 12 14]]` is -13 not -273.

Comment: The matrix that i indicate had a 2 instead of a 12.

Comment: Apart from the type of `m` being incorrect, as @ardget mentioned., also make it a habit to use [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) for sizes, counts and indices into arrays.

Comment: "Since the Gaussian elimination works" Nope it doesn't (even after you replace `int` with `T`.) There are in fact several problems. First, what happens if your `T` **is** `int`? An algorithm that incorporates division will clearly not work. Second, try this matrix `{0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0}`. Is it really singular? Your algorithm thinks it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little inspection, I think I've found your problem.
You've made a simple mistake defining one of your key variables ***m***. This is as you know, the main scaler in Gaussian elimination, and its job is to zero out the next row's element.
Instead of defining it as `int m = 0` you should've defined it as `float m = 0` or `double m = 0`.
Also, in the line that you calculate **m** you need to force cast the operands of the division to the appropriate types. So after redefining **m**, you should change this line:

```c
m = Tri.Mat[i*Cols + k]/Tri.Mat[k*Cols + k]
```

to this

```c
m = Tri.Mat[i*Cols + k] / (double)Tri.Mat[k*Cols + k]
```

Keep in mind that you're template type should be *double* as well or again this will not work.

Also, I recommend you to take a look at [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-drawbacks-of-the-Gauss-elimination-method-and-the-strategies-to-mitigate-What-is-pivoting-in-regard-to-this-method) to understand some of Gaussian Elimination's limits. There are some cases in which the algorithm will not work effectively.